# Насколько надежно использовать Timer для переподключения Android веб приложения к серверу?

Tags: android, клиент-сервер, java-timer

Клиент реализован так, что каждые 2 минуты приложение переподключается, если сервер не отправил автоматический запрос для проверки соединения. Сервер же каждые 40 минут шлёт запрос. Timer() как раз и реализует ожидание и я вызываю Timer.cancel() для сброса таймера, если сообщения от сервера пришло.

Я относительно не давно в Android разработке и я бы хотел узнать, надежно ли использовать Timer()? Или лучше использовать внутренние часы Android OS чтобы не плодить потоки, например? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054940/what-is-the-best-approach-in-connecting-to-server-periodically-and-check-for-upd)

Comment: Идея интересная, но не совсем мне подходит. Моё приложение не работает с Google

Answer (score 0):

Timer не является надежным, AlarmManager нужно использовать. Такой ответ я нашел на просторах stackoverflow:
-- ИСТОЧНИК: https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.0b26a902-64a4d199-55e5c854-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/8998386/to-start-my-application-while-screen-is-locked

Comment: я вам дал ссылку там в первом же комментарии написано было про это...